# Java variable visibitlity

Tags: java, variables, scope, initialization, disambiguation

I have the following code:

```
public class Java0102
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x = 2;
        int y = 10;
        if (x == 2)
        {
            x = 5;
            int w = y * x;
        }
        System.out.println("W="+w);
        int W = x*y*w;
        y = x;
        System.out.println("New W="+w);
        System.out.println("X="+x);
        System.out.println("Y="+y);
    }
}
```

when i try to compile it on bluej it says cannot find symbol - variable w
but since the if statement runs because x == 2 shouldn't java presume the variable w is initialized and so exists?

Comment: Well i can understand the scope but i tought that the scope changes if a method is called and inside the method a declared variable is local so not visible outside. Is it the same thing with if statements? it changes scope??

Comment: so if i make a variable(declare it) inside an if statement java considers it as a different inside scope so it isn't visible outside the if block at main.. I am trying to see if i have grapsed the concept here... thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `w` is declared inside the `if` block code, which means it will be accesible only in that scope: the block code of the `if` statement. After that block, the variable `w` doesn't exist anymore, thus the compiler error is valid.

To solve this, just declare and initialize the variable before the `if` statement.

```
int w = 1;
if (x == 2) {
    x = 5;
    w = y * x;
}
```

From your comment in the question:

> I tought that the scope changes if a method is called and inside the method a declared variable is local so not visible outside. Is it the same thing with if statements? it changes scope?

You're confusing the concepts of class variable i.e. a field and local method variable (commonly known as variable). The fields in the class will be initialized when you create an instance of the class, while the variables in a method have a specific scope that depends of the block code they are declared.

This means, you can have this code compiling and running (doesn't mean you have to write code like this):

```
public class SomeClass {
    int x; //field
    public void someMethod(int a, int b) {
        int x = a + b;
        //this refers to the variable in the method
        System.out.println(x);
        //this refers to the variable in the class i.e. the field
        //recognizable by the usage of this keyword
        System.out.println(this.x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your `w` variable needs to be declared outside of the if statement. Otherwise it it out of [Scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html).

```
public class Java0102
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x = 2;
        int y = 10;
        int w = 1;  //declare and initialize your lowercase-w variable

        if (x == 2)
        {
            x = 5;
            w = y * x; //perform your arithmetic
        }
        System.out.println("W="+w);
        int W = x*y*w;
        y = x;
        System.out.println("New W="+w);
        System.out.println("X="+x);
        System.out.println("Y="+y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your w is only visible in this block:

{
            x = 5;
            int w = y * x;
 }

So, outside it, you cannot access to it.
If you want ,
you can define w outside {} block.

Such as

```
int w = 0;
{
            x = 5;
            w = y * x;
}
```